# Visual Studio - autogeneration files

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I use in my c++ project google buffer protocol lib. And after changing *.proto files in my solution I need regenerate *.cpp files using google buffer protocol compiler. How can do it before compilation? Pre-buid events is not acceptable for me.

Answer (score 1):

Add the file to the project. Select the item in the solution explorer. Select properties and change its build type to custom, and accept it. Now do it again and you'll can add the information for building it.

Comment: Quick addndum to that answer - you might have to specify the stage for executing the protobuf compiler at the Custom Build Step options in the project properties.